# What does find list operation return if not found?

Tags: mendix

I am using the "Find" list operation in Mendix and I would like to know what it returns if the item is not found. I could not find anything on the mendix site.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple: it will return `empty` (Mendix' version of a null reference). It won't throw an error, but it might e.g. when the rest of the code attempts to change the empty object. It's recommended to test the result of Find with an exclusive split (the orange diamond).